# What is the use of System.getProperty() while taking Screenshot in Selenium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-extent-report, takesscreenshot

I'm running a program for adding screenshot in extent report automatically using selenium. Program is running perfectly,but I want to know the meaning of System.getProperty line in below program .

```
public class SST 
{
    public static String getScreenshot(WebDriver driver)
    {
    TakesScreenshot ts=(TakesScreenshot) driver;
        File src=ts.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    String path = System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/Screenshot/"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".png";
        File destination=new File(path);

        try 
        {
            FileUtils.copyFile(src, destination);
        } catch (IOException e) 
        {
            System.out.println("Capture Failed "+e.getMessage());
        }
        return path;
    }
}
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint on that line and step through it and see what it returns. Write it to console, etc. There are a lot of ways to figure this out... which have you tried? Did you look up the documentation? Is there something you are confused about? Please clarify your question.

Comment: I just wanted to know the background process of that line.

Comment: Great, then you can start with all the suggestions I made in my first comment and if you still don't understand, then you can ask a question with a clear statement of what you have tried/read and what you specifically don't understand. Right now it seems like you haven't done ANY research into your problem and just dumped some code and asked us to explain it to you... that may not be the actual case but that's what it seems like.

Answer (score 0):

It is getting the user home directory, for example, `C:\Users\user10796675`.

Comment: could you be little more specific i.e where my screenshot is saved ?

Comment: It should be something like `C:\Users\user10796675\Screenshot\2019-05-20.png`. It really depends on your username (the one you are logging in to windows with) and the time the screenshot was taken.

Comment: If you found the answer useful, you can upvote and/or accept it.